# Restrict access to specific widget field based on user role

Tags: themes, widgets

I'm looking for a way to restrict the ability to drag certain widgets to specific widget areas in the widget editor.

For example, I would like to restrict the widget field 'ads' to only be available to administrators. I would be quite happy if I could do this by disabling the ability to drag-n-drop in these fields.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to simply not display it to other user roles?

Comment: I ended up hiding the area to drop it in.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding the class 'ab-ads' to all my widget areas.

```
if ( !is_super_admin() ) {
  add_action('admin_print_styles-widgets.php', function() {
      echo '<style type="text/css">div.sidebar-widgets-ab-ads { display:none; }</style>';
  });
}
```

That way I just hide them for everyone that isn't administrators.

Comment: If you got someone as a user, who knows how to use Chrome Dev Tools, FireBug, etc. then they will have full access. Not that cool, right?

Comment: kaiser: True, but that won't be an issue in this setup.